# I not able to decode JSON data in swift

Tags: php, json, swift, decode

I am trying to create simple login and signup in swift with php mysql in backend. I was following "https://github.com/EMacco/ios-tutorials/tree/yummie-network-connection/Yummie" this project

I get the following error

The response is: {"data":[{"response":"Success","username":"Mohammad Tariq Shamim"}]} Error Response could not be decoded

I am getting response from the server but JSON is not getting decoded. Following is my code

```
enum Route {
    static let baseurl = "http://arabscholar.net/android/"
    case login
    var description: String {
        switch self {
        case .login: return "login.php"
        }
    }
}

struct User: Decodable{     let username: String?     let response: String? }

struct ApiResponse<T: Decodable>: Decodable {
    let status: Int
    let data: T?
    let error: String?
}
```

AppError Swift file

```
enum AppError: LocalizedError {
    case errorDecoding
    case unknownError
    case invalidUrl
    case serverError(String)
    
    var errorDescription: String? {
        switch self {
            
        case .errorDecoding:
            return "Response could not be decoded"
        case .unknownError:
            return "Unknown error"
        case .invalidUrl:
            return "Url invalid"
        case .serverError(let error):
            return error
        }
    }
}
```

Main networking struct file

```
struct NetworkService {
    static let shared = NetworkService()
    private init() {}
    func signin(username: String, password: String, completion: @escaping(Result<User, Error>) -> Void) {
        let params = ["login": "user", "email": username, "password": password]
            
        request(route: .login, method: .post, parameters: params, completion: completion)
    }
    
    private func request<T: Decodable>(route: Route, method: Method, parameters: [String: Any]? = nil, completion: @escaping(Result<T, Error>) -> Void) {
        guard let request = createRequest(route: route, method: method, parameters: parameters) else {
            completion(.failure(AppError.unknownError))
            return
        }
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            var result: Result<Data, Error>?
            if let data = data {
                result = .success(data)
                let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) ?? "Could not stringify our data"
                print("The response is: (responseString)")
            } else if let error = error {
                result = .failure(error)
                print("The error is " + error.localizedDescription)
            }
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.handleResponse(result: result, completion: completion)
            }
            
        }.resume()
    }
    
    private func handleResponse<T: Decodable>(result: Result<Data, Error>?, completion: (Result<T, Error>) -> Void) {
        guard let result = result else {
            completion(.failure(AppError.unknownError))
            return
        }
            
        switch result {
        case .success(let data):
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            guard let response = try? decoder.decode(ApiResponse.self, from: data) else {
                completion(.failure(AppError.errorDecoding))
                return
            }
                
            if let error = response.error {
                completion(.failure(AppError.serverError(error)))
                return
            }
            
            if let decodedData = response.data {
                completion(.success(decodedData))
            } else {
                completion(.failure(AppError.unknownError))
            }
        case .failure(let error):
            completion(.failure(error))
        }
    }
    
    private func createRequest(route: Route, method: Method, parameters: [String: Any]? = nil) -> URLRequest? {
        let urlString = Route.baseurl + route.description
        guard let url = urlString.asUrl else {return nil}
        var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
        urlRequest.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        urlRequest.httpMethod = method.rawValue
        
        if let params = parameters {
            switch method {
            case .get:
                var urlComponent = URLComponents(string: urlString)
                urlComponent?.queryItems = params.map { URLQueryItem(name: $0, value: "($1)")}
                urlRequest.url = urlComponent?.url
            case .post:
                let bodyData = try?JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params, options: [])
                urlRequest.httpBody = bodyData
            }
        }
        return urlRequest
    }
}
```

My PHP code

```
$postdata = json_decode( file_get_contents( "php://input" ), TRUE );

  //$id = $postdata[ "email" ];
  //$name = $postdata[ "password" ];
  $result[ 'response' ] = "Success";
  $result[ 'username' ] = "Mohammad Tariq Shamim";
  // Store values in an array
  $returnValue = array( $result );

  $array['data'] = $returnValue;
  // Send back request in JSON format
  echo json_encode( $array );
  //echo json_encode( array( 'response' => 'No data found for ' . $_POST[ 'email' ] ) );
```

Comment: `ApiResponse` being? Also, don't do `try? `, use a proper do/try/catch that will throw an error with explicit error giving useful information on why it failed.

Comment: can you show more code in `User` model?

Comment: I have only this in User Model

struct User: Decodable{
    let username: String?
    let response: String?
}

Comment: You are decoding a single `User`, however, your JSON data are an array. Try this `[User].self`

Comment: I am new to swift. Can you please guide

Comment: @Larme can you please guide. I am new to swift

Comment: The `T` in `APIResponse` according to your JSON is a `[User]`, not `User`. It's strange that's an array since it's a login ONE user. So either change it on server side, or handle that you are decoding `[User]`.

Comment: @son I tried as you said but still the same error

Comment: @Larme at server side I tried with {"response":"Success","username":"Mohammad Tariq Shamim"} also but same error

Comment: Then there is no `data` field? Try `$array['data'] = $return` instead? Unrelated, but in PhP, `$array` isn't an Array, it's a Dictionary.